# Can you please confirm me "Will Selenium + Java configuration work fully aligned with PHP/ Laravel codebase ?? "

Tags: selenium

i am new to Selenium+Java Automation .i want to confirm that is Selenium+Java will work fine for PHP/Laravel codebase ?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? Usually, Selenium should not care how the pages that should be tested are generated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.